# A PHP Error was encountered with core/Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi am trying Basic CRUD Operation with MySQL Database with example and am new in this platform am facing some problem please help

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Products::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 73

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\models\ProductsModel.php
Line: 9
Function: __get

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\controllers\Products.php
Line: 17
Function: get_products

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function get() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\models\ProductsModel.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\application\controllers\Products.php
Line: 17
Function: get_products

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.9\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: You have supplied the exception, but not the actual code you're running. But without looking at your code it's hard to tell what's wrong here.

Comment: what is the code of your controller Products.php and model ProductModel.php?

Comment: Thank you sir for your replay

Comment: make sure you have loaded `database` and `model`

Comment: It maybe solve with load library of database in autoload.php